# Best way to store images sent from iBooks widget

Tags: javascript, html, cross-domain, ibooks

I'm creating an ibooks widget (which is an HTML page).
The HTML has an input (type="file") that collects reader images directly from the device.

**How can I send those images to my server in order to store them** considering that I'm in an iBook with no specific domain?

IDEA 1: send images via Ajax (which seams daunting).

IDEA 2: create an iframe where I directly call my server (but how to avoid 'X-Frame-Options' if I don't have a URI to whitelist?).

If anyone has an idea it'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out that the best would be option A avoiding X-Frame-Options all together.

See [this guide](http://jerodsanto.net/2013/12/rails-4-let-specific-actions-be-embedded-as-iframes/).